# Time offset format with City names in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Is there a way of formatting time offset like this using c#?

```
07:53:21 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

This is what I've try:

```
public string BuildHourMinute(DateTime time)
{
    string format = "H:mm (zzzz)";
    return time.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

***Note: Value of time is different time from local time.***
With this I´m getting:

```
13:00 (+02:00)
```

Comment: You can use `TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DaylightName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.daylightname?view=netcore-3.1) property from `TimeZoneInfo` class and `HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz` format string for correct representation

```cs
public string BuildHourMinute(DateTime time)
{
    return $"{time:HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz} {TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName}";
}
```

The important point here is to put `GMT` into single quotes, otherwise `M` will treated as month format specifier.

Another option is to use [`DisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.displayname?view=netcore-3.1) property, but you still need an access to `TimeZoneInfo` object

```cs
public string BuildHourMinute(DateTime time)
{
    return $"{time:HH:mm:ss} {TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName}";
}
```

Comment: this gives me the format for the local time and not the value of time

Comment: @CarlosMartins where does your timezone come from?

Comment: time values are stored with timezone info. With return time.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); I get 13:00 (+02:00). I should get also the city names. TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName gives me the right format but not for the value I´m passing to the method

Comment: @CarlosMartins which time value are you passing to the method? With `DateTime.Now` I'm getting `11:00:59 GMT+03:00 ......` string in my end. Where does `13:00 (+02:00)` come from? Does `time` parameter have the correct `DateTimeKind` value set?

Answer (score 1):

in `toString()` for DateTime:

1. HH stands for hours
2. mm for minutes
3. ss for seconds
4. zzz to get the BaseUtcOffset
   finally to get the region with day light timing , you should use

   ```
   TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName
   ```

and you final statment should look like this:

```
   timeAsWanted = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss GMT(zzz)") + TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName
```

Comment: Also this gives me the info for the local time and not the value of time. The format is the correct one